# How to use a div tag as a target place (JSP)?

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a `home.jsp` page and a `login.jsp` page

**home.jsp**

i have 3 div tags as

```
div id="header"    
div id="content"    
div id="footer"
```

1) When i click on `Login` link in `home.jsp` page it redirects to login.jsp page,`i need:` it should be shown on div id="content" tag in home.jsp page.

**My Requirement is** ::  The `home.jsp` should be my home page..the header and the footer should not change,
                        only the content which ever changes should be displayed in the div tag with `id="content"`

By using frames i am able to solve this,as we have target=".....", but is there any posssibility of achieving the same using div tag ?

Please Explain with an Example!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868890/ajax-how-refresh-div-after-submit

Comment: @0mile i'm using jsp and java beans :-) is it using ajax is the only way to do that..!!

Comment: It is client side stuff. There is only one way to do i.e. ajax. It doesn't depend whether you are using JSP, PHP, Ruby or .Net

Comment: i'm not that familiar with ajax @0mile can u give a good solution which solves the way i need :-) a direct example pls

Comment: http://try.jquery.com/

Comment: are you will do this just with html5 method?

Comment: @user2561626 I'd suggest you put in a bit of effort with AJAX, try something, come back with any specific queries & raise questions against it. You'll get very little help if you're asking someone else to solve it for you wholesale without any effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you will decorator. you will your theme most be fixed in all pages. you can do this with any decorator framework like sitemesh(`http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home`).
if you will do this without decorator framework you can do as following:

- create header.jsp
- create footer.jsp
- create home.jsp page as following:
   `<body>

      <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />

       ....

       home content

       ....

      <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />

  </body>`
- create login.jsp as following :
  `<body>

      <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />

       ....

       login content

       ....

      <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />

  </body>`

i suggest you use a decorator framework. thats better.

Comment: u are right:-) but using this the page loads every time !!! thank u @rasoul taheri