# Jquery/JavaScript - How to refresh a div after form submit without page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, partial-page-refresh

I am injecting the following code into a specific page. The code refreshes a specific DIV class every 3 seconds without reloading the entire page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('.activity-comments').load(location.href + ' .activity-comments')
}, 3000);
});
```

I would like to change this code so that it only refreshes the DIV class after a specific form is submitted (without reloading the entire page). Below are the details of the form:

```
<form class="comment-form" action="/comment/reply/111" method="post" id="comment-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Comment" class="form-submit art-button ajax-processed">
```

I'm not sure if using .load is the most optimized method for doing this. How can I change my code to achieve this?

Comment: Please take a look if it can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868890/ajax-how-refresh-div-after-submit#answer-869049

Comment: I have tried to use the solution on that page but it doesn't refresh the div after submit. Below is my code:

``jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#comment-form").submit(function() {
  var options = {
   /* target:"#divResult", */

   success: function(html) {
    $(".activity-comments").replaceWith($('.activity-comments', $(html)));
   },
   url: location.href + ' .activity-comments'
  }
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
  return false;
 });
});``